# Extract the Data from Json to Table where Id is in Key

Tags: python, json, sql-server, json-query

I am trying to covert the below Json to table using SQL Function JSON_QUERY ( expression [ , path ] ). When i use this i am unable to define the path as Id is in the key and id's change overtime. Is there any way we can convert/load this json format to a table?

Comment: please let us know how you attempted to solve the problem (simple working code example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using the OPENJSON table valued function:

```
SELECT  ch.[key] as checklistId, 
        JSON_VALUE (ch.[value] ,'$.isChecked') as isChecked,
        JSON_VALUE (ch.[value],'$.orderHint') as orderHint

FROM OPENJSON (@json,'$.checklist') ch;
```